# nodejs can't get data from sqlite db

Tags: node.js, typescript, sqlite

This is my simple code to get some data from my sqlite db.

Index.ts:

```
import { Database } from './Class/database';
Database.checkIfExists("some ID");
```

Database.ts:

```
export class Database {

    static sqlite3 = require("sqlite3").verbose();
    static db = new Database.sqlite3.Database("database.db");

    static checkIfExists(memberID: string) {
        Database.db.run("SELECT * FROM Points WHERE DiscordID = $discordID", {
            $discordID: memberID
        }, function (err:any, row:any) {
            console.log(row);
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
}
```

Do you guys have any idea why the first log does `undefined` and the second one `null`? Even with just "SELECT * FROM Points" I get the same. Running this query directly in the sql db browser will show me the correct data.

---

Edit:

Code for better testing:

```
checkIfExists(memberID: string) {
        this.db.run("SELECT * FROM Points", function (err:any, row:any) {
            console.log(row);
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Method checkIfExists cannot be static as it is instance specific. Should be like this:

```js
export class Database {

    private sqlite3 = require("sqlite3").verbose();
    private db = new Database.sqlite3.Database("database.db");

    checkIfExists(memberID: string) {
        this.db.run("SELECT * FROM Points WHERE DiscordID = $discordID", {
            $discordID: memberID
        }, function (err:any, row:any) {
            console.log(row);
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I wanted that the class is somewhat static so I can call this class and the functions without the need to make an instance. I think that should work, sqlite3 and db variables are correct and also the sql call does "work". For example if the table doesn't exist I get that error message. The only problem is why I can't get any data even if the same query does work inside the sql browser.

Comment: Static methods should not depend on external variables.
Connecting to the database should only happen once, not with every request. To do this, you first need to make the DbConnect class and transfer its instance to another class. In order not to create an instance myself, I recommend studying the topic of IoC or using inversify or nest.js. You also need to use some kind of ORM (for example, typeORM or prisma.io).

Comment: Ok for testing I rewrite it like your answere but it still just logs me `undefined` and `null`

Comment: Most likely because it takes time to connect to the database. As I wrote above, the connection to the database should occur only once, at the start of the application. And only after the connection to the database has been established, the rest of the functions should be performed.